# implement interface or class for dependency

Tags: java

I have the following Java code that I need to figure out how it's implemented:

```
public interface ICalculationContext {
}

...
 ICalculationContext calculationContext = null;
    if (1 == 1) {
      ScheduledContext scheduledContext = (ScheduledContext) transaction.getContext();
      calculationContext = ScheduledFeeContext.builder()
          .productConfig(null).agreementId(scheduledContext.getAgreementId()).build();
    return calculationContext;
...

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ScheduledContext extends BaseContext {

  @NotNull
  private UUID agreementId;

  @NotNull
  private String feeCode;

}
```

I get error for this these line:

```
calculationContext = ScheduledFeeContext.builder()
          .productConfig(null).agreementId(scheduledContext.getAgreementId()).build();
```

Required type: ICalculationContext
Provided: ScheduledFeeContext

Do you know what code I need to implement for `ICalculationContext` in order to fix this?

Comment: It would help to know what `ScheduledContext#getAgreementId`, `BaseContext`, `#getContext`, `ScheduledFeeContext`, `#builder`, `productConfig`,  and `#agreementId` all do, as well as any libraries you are using in this scenario relevant to the code shown.

Comment: You should provide a minimal but reproducible example of your project

Comment: Sounds like `ScheduledFeeContext` does not implement `ICalculationContext`, but can't be sure. It would help to show declaration for `ScheduledFeeContext`, as well the method signature , where you try to return the context.

Comment: ICalculationContext should be a class or a Interface?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `ScheduledFeeContext` class does not implement `ICalculationContext`
You must show us the declaration of `ScheduledFeeContext`

Comment: I tried this and it works but I have a question: `ICalculationContext` should be a class or a Interface?

Comment: There is no right answer. In general, if the name starts with I, it should be an interface. It all depends on the code, but proper use of the interface allows you to decouple a class from its implementation and make testing easier. I recommend you to look at IoC and Dependency injection concepts